# Trying to filter a row from master sheet that doesn't get copied to individual during macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

So I have my master sheet that I run a macro on to copy a template and then populate with certain rows based off of values in one column. I need to add a check in so that I can tell it not to pull the row if the value in another column matches a specified criteria.  For example, row x would get pulled if the value in column Y matches 1234, but only if the value in column Z does not match 456. This is the code I am using right now:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Report()
    CreateDeptReport "Report"
End Sub


Sub CreateDeptReport(Report As String)

    Dim shtRpt As Excel.Worksheet, shtMaster As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim LCopyToRow As Long
    Dim LCopyToCol As Long
    Dim arrColsToCopy
    Dim c As Range, X As Integer

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    arrColsToCopy = Array(1, 3, 4, 8, 25, 16, 17, 15, 31, 7, 26) 'which columns to copy ?

    Set shtMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData")
    Set c = shtMaster.Range("Y5")  'Start search in Row 5

    LCopyToRow = 10 'Start copying data to row 10 in Mental

    While Len(c.Value) > 0
        'If value in column Y ends with "2135", copy to report sheet
       If c.Value Like "*2135" Then

            'only create the new sheet if any records are found
            If shtRpt Is Nothing Then
                'delete any existing sheet
                On Error Resume Next
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NewSheetName").Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                On Error GoTo 0
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy After:=shtMaster
                Set shtRpt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shtMaster.Index + 1)
                shtRpt.Name = "NewSheetName" 'rename new sheet to NewSheetName
                Range("F1").Value = "XXXX"
                Range("F2").Value = "XXXX"
                Range("B3").Value = Date
                Range("B4").Value = "XXXX"            
            End If

            LCopyToCol = 1

            shtRpt.Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

            For X = LBound(arrColsToCopy) To UBound(arrColsToCopy)

                shtRpt.Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).Value = _
                            c.EntireRow.Cells(arrColsToCopy(X)).Value

                LCopyToCol = LCopyToCol + 1

            Next X

            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1 'next row
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NewSheetName").Rows("9:9").Delete

    Range("A9").Select 'Position on cell A9
    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
        MsgBox "An error occurred."
End Sub
```

This is what I've got; I'd like to do as little restructuring as possible since I know this does exactly what I want save this one stupid wrinkle. I've tried adding in conditions around the c.Value line but I'm not getting anywhere. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first criteria range is labelled "c" so let's called your second one "d".  Add in these lines in the appropriate places:

1. Right after all your other Dim statements, add
   `Dim d as range`
2. After the `set c` line, add
   `Set d = shtMaster.Range("Y5")`
3. Change
   `If c.Value Like "*2135" Then` to
   `If c.Value Like "*2135" and d.Value not like "*456*" Then`
4. Right before `Wend` add
   `Set d = d.Offset(1, 0)`

I might have missed a line or two, but basically I'm trying to keep the same logic pattern and duplicate the lines that changed your `c` variable.  (If I missed a line or two, please point them out in the comments)

Comment: You know I was doing this earlier and kept getting error messages. I guess I just needed time away from it to see what I was doing wrong. Your change in #3 above (as mine was previously as well) is incorrect. 1,2, and 4 is ok. 3 should read: `If c.Value Like "*2135" and Not d.Value Like "456" Then`